# gdb vague shared library event information

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I've made gdb to stop at shared library events. When I continue running application and gdb breaks saying:
"Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)"

If I look at backtrace, it shows call to dlopen().

What does this mean? Is it that application tried to open shared library that was already loaded, or something else? Unfortunately I don't have symbols for libdl to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it that application tried to open shared library that was already loaded

Yes.